# How can I convert a String into ArrayList by counting occurrence of each characters?

Tags: java, json

I have a Input String as :

```
String str="1,1,2,2,2,1,3";
```

I want count each id occurrence and store them into List,and I want output Like this:

```
 [
  {
   "count": "3",
    "ids": "1, 2"
   }
   {
     "count": "1",
      "ids": "3"
    }
      ]
```

I tried by using `org.springframework.util.StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(input, "a");` like this. But after counting not getting the things like I want.

Comment: Thank you, that's very important information for the readers of your question. That's why your last comment belongs inside the question. Click [edit], and write the same thing at the end of your question, and also explain what incorrect output you got from the attempt.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the desired result. You first count the occurrences of each character, then you group by count each character in a new `HashMap<Integer, List<String>>`.

Here's a working example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "1,1,2,2,2,1,3";

    String[] list = str.split(",");
    HashMap<String, Integer> occr = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (occr.containsKey(list[i])) {
            occr.put(list[i], occr.get(list[i]) + 1);
        } else {
            occr.put(list[i], 1);
        }
    }
    HashMap<Integer, List<String>> res = new HashMap<>();
    for (String key : occr.keySet()) {
        int count = occr.get(key);
        if (res.containsKey(count)) {
            res.get(count).add(key);
        } else {
            List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
            l.add(key);
            res.put(count, l);
        }
    }

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("[\n");
    for (Integer count : res.keySet()) {
        sb.append("{\n");
        List<String> finalList = res.get(count);
        sb.append("\"count\":\"" + count + "\",\n");
        sb.append("\"ids\":\"" + finalList.get(0));
        for (int i = 1; i < finalList.size(); i++) {
            sb.append("," + finalList.get(i));
        }
        sb.append("\"\n}\n");

    }
    sb.append("\n]");
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
}
```

**EDIT:** A more generalised solution

Here's the method that returns a `HashMap<Integer,List<String>>`, which contains the number of occurrences of a string as a key of the `HashMap` where each key has a `List<String>` value which contains all the strings that occur **key** number of times.

```
public HashMap<Integer, List<String>> countOccurrences(String str, String delimiter) {
    // First, we count the number of occurrences of each string.
    String[] list = str.split(delimiter);
    HashMap<String, Integer> occr = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (occr.containsKey(list[i])) {
            occr.put(list[i], occr.get(list[i]) + 1);
        } else {
            occr.put(list[i], 1);
        }
    }
    /** Now, we group them by the number of occurrences,
     * All strings with the same number of occurrences are put into a list;
     * this list is put into a HashMap as a value, with the number of 
     * occurrences as a key.
     */
    HashMap<Integer, List<String>> res = new HashMap<>();
    for (String key : occr.keySet()) {
        int count = occr.get(key);
        if (res.containsKey(count)) {
            res.get(count).add(key);
        } else {
            List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
            l.add(key);
            res.put(count, l);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: If it solved your problem, please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer by clicking the big checkbox on the left upper corner. It will help other to find the correct answer to your question. Thank you!

Comment: @KarthikeyanKR, the output is in the `HashMap<Integer, List<String>> res` object. Its keys represent the count, and the values the list of the characters. You can choose how you want to display it. I just added the code snipped to process it into a `StringBuffer` and show the result (for the sake of simplicity). You can choose to display it some other way, too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some boring transfer, I'm not sure if you want to keep the ids sorted. A simple implementation is:

```
    public List<Map<String, Object>> countFrequency(String s) {
    // Count by char
    Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String ch : s.split(",")) {
        Integer count = countMap.get(ch);
        if (count == null) {
            count = 0;
        }
        count++;
        countMap.put(ch, count);
    }

    // Count by frequency
    Map<Integer, String> countByFrequency = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : countMap.entrySet()) {
        String chars = countByFrequency.get(entry.getValue());

        System.out.println(entry.getValue() + " " + chars);

        if (chars == null) {
            chars = "" + entry.getKey();
        } else {
            chars += ", " + entry.getKey();
        }
        countByFrequency.put(entry.getValue(), chars);
    }

    // Convert to list
    List<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : countByFrequency.entrySet()) {
        Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        item.put("count", entry.getKey());
        item.put("ids", entry.getValue());
        result.add(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey check the below code, it help you to achieve your expected result

```
public class Test
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
     String str = "1,1,2,2,2,1,3"; //Your input string

     List<String> listOfIds = Arrays.asList(str.split(",")); //Splits the string
     System.out.println("List of IDs : " + listOfIds);

     HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
     Set<String> uniqueIds = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));
     for (String uniqueId : uniqueIds)
     {
        String frequency = String.valueOf(Collections.frequency(listOfIds, uniqueId));
        System.out.println("ID = " + uniqueId + ", frequency = " + frequency);

        if (!map.containsKey(frequency))
        {
            map.put(frequency, new ArrayList<String>());
        }
        map.get(frequency).add(uniqueId);
     }

     for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet())
     {
        System.out.println("Count = "+ entry.getKey() + ", IDs = " + entry.getValue());
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach i can suggest you is to
put each "character" in hashMap as a key and "count" as a value.
Sample code to do so is

```
    String str = "1,1,2,2,2,1,3";
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap();
    for (String c : str.split(",")) {
        if (map.containsKey( c)) {
            int count = Integer.parseInt(map.get(c));
            map.put(c, ++count + "");
        } else
            map.put(c, "1");
    }
    System.out.println(map.toString());
}
```

Comment: This won't give the final result, it just finds the count for each character.

Comment: If you want to print the information in above format you can write a code by iterating Entry Set of Hash Map. However , List is not a type of Data Structure to store this type of information - One is "String" and another is count,

Comment: You can declare the `map` object to be `HashMap<String, Integer>`, this way you won't have to parse the `String` value to `int` as you have done here `int count = Integer.parseInt(map.get(c));`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--first you split string based on "," and store into array, after that iterate array end of array lenght in side loop  create new map and put element in map as a Key and set value as count 1 again check the key and increase count value in map-->
like....



  String str="1,1,2,2,2,1,3";
    String strArray=str.split(",");
    Map strMap=  new hashMap();
    for(int i=0; i < strArray.length(); i++){
    if(!strMap.containsKey(strArray[i])){
    strMap.put(strArray[i],1)
    }else{
    strMap.put(strArray[i],strMap.get(strArray[i])+1)
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="1,1,2,2,2,1,3";
    //Converting given string to string array
    String[] strArray = str.split(",");
    //Creating a HashMap containing char as a key and occurrences as  a value
    Map<String,Integer> charCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
     //checking each element of strArray
    for(String num :strArray){
        if(charCountMap.containsKey(num))
        {
            //If char is present in charCountMap, incrementing it's count by 1
            charCountMap.put(num, charCountMap.get(num)+1);
        }
        else
        {
            //If char is not present in charCountMap, and putting this char to charCountMap with 1 as it's value
            charCountMap.put(num, 1);
        }
    }
     //Printing the charCountMap
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : charCountMap.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println("ID ="+entry.getKey() + "   count=" + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Split according to comma
    HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String key : tokens) {
        if (hm.containsKey(key)) {
            Integer currentCount = hm.get(key);
            hm.put(key, ++currentCount);
        } else {
            hm.put(key, 1);
        }
    }

    // Organize info according to ID
    HashMap<Integer, String> result = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : hm.entrySet()) {

        Integer newKey = entry.getValue();
        if (result.containsKey(newKey)) {
            String newValue = entry.getKey() + ", " + result.get(newKey);
            result.put(newKey, newValue);
        } else {
            result.put(newKey, entry.getKey());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is a complete **Java 8 streaming solution** for the problem. The main idea is to first build a map of the occurances of each id, which results in:

```
{1=3, 2=3, 3=1}
```

(first is ID and second the count) and then to group by it by the count:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "1,1,2,2,2,1,3";

    System.out.println(
         Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(str)
                 .collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting()))
                 .entrySet().stream()
                 .collect(groupingBy(i -> i.getValue(), mapping( i -> i.getKey(), toList())))
    );
}
```

which results in:

```
{1=[3], 3=[1, 2]}
```

This is the most compact version I could come up with. Is there anything even smaller?

---

**EDIT:** By the way here is the complete class, to get all static method imports right:

```
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class Java8StreamsTest6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "1,1,2,2,2,1,3";

        System.out.println(
                Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(str)
                        .collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting()))
                        .entrySet().stream()
                        .collect(groupingBy(i -> i.getValue(), mapping(i -> i.getKey(), toList())))
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: What's `groupingBy(...)`, `idenity()`, `toList()` and `couting()`? The compiler cannot find any of these methods. Do I have to write them all? I'm using Java 8.

Comment: Ah. I should have posted the whole class. These are static imports.

Comment: I added the complete class to my answer.